# How can I deploy an SPL fungible token through anchor?

Tags: anchor, program

I attempt to create a new account with the anchor `#[account(init)]` macro, then assign ownership of the new account to the `token program`, and then attempt to send the `initialize_mint` instruction to the `token program` via a CPI call.

But I seem to always get the following error:

```
     Error: AnchorError caused by account: mint. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P
Program log: Right:
Program log: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
```

My code:

```
#[program]
pub mod pump {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>) -> Result<()> {
        // assign ownership of the mint account to the token program
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().assign(&token::ID);

        // Create a new token mint
        let cpi_accounts = InitializeMint {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        };

        let decimals = 9;
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.clone().to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        token::initialize_mint(cpi_ctx, decimals, &ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), None)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = Mint::LEN)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(seeds = [b"mint-authority"], bump)]
    /// CHECK: The mint authority is the program derived address.
    pub mint_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```

This error goes away if I change the `Create` struct to use an `UncheckedAccount`:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = Mint::LEN)]
    /// CHECK: foobar
    pub mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>, // by changing this to be UncheckedAccount
    // ... snip ...
}
```

What is going on here? Why does it work when I change from `Account<'info, Mint>` to `UncheckedAccount<'info>`? Is it safe to do this? Is there a better way of fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io/https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-examples/tree/main/account-constraints/mint) you can reference.

You don't need the cpis in the instruction logic. When creating a mint account, Anchor handles those for you through the constraints.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, Token};

declare_id!("3bA9ovdNzycPGkdF8Pt31gxkV4BNzgZ2iKhWTpF5FcME");

#[program]
pub mod example {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Created Mint Account: {}", ctx.accounts.mint.key());
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn account_validation(ctx: Context<AccountValidation>) -> Result<()> {
        // Checked that `signer` is the both mint and freeze authority of `mint
        msg!("Mint : {}", ctx.accounts.mint.key());
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = signer,
        mint::freeze_authority = signer
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AccountValidation<'info> {
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mint::authority = signer,
        mint::freeze_authority = signer
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
}
```

Comment: In this example, the `example` program would be the owner of the Mint account. Shouldn't the owner of the Mint account be the Token program (because it needs to be able to do edit data such as incrementing the supply when new mints occur in the Mint account)?

Comment: When using `init` with the `Mint` type, Anchor will handle creating the Mint Account owned by the token program. This is also the case for token accounts.

Comment: Are there any other special cases like this? How does anchor know to point the mint account owner to the token program instead of the example program?